Generalising the transformation of the probability density function to $R^n$
According to this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236840/different-probability-density-transformations-due-to-jacobian-factor
we have $$p_y(y) = p_x(x) |\frac{dx}{dy}|.$$
Ideally I would like to show that this holds for probability density functions on $n$-dimensional space. I have started with $R^2$.
What I have said is the following:
Observations falling in the area $[x_1, x_1 + \delta x_1] \times [x_2, x_2 + \delta x_2]$ will be mapped to $[y_1, y_1 + \delta y_1] \times [y_2, y_2 + \delta y_2]$, where $p_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})\delta x_1\delta x_2 = p_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{y})\delta y_1\delta y_2$. This implies that:
$$ p_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x}) = p_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{y})\frac{\delta y_1\delta y_2}{\delta x_1\delta x_2}$$
What is the entity on the right? I can generalise this easily to $n$-dimensional space, but I will just end up with a higher dimensional entity.
I think it has something to do with the Jacobian, but I can not make the theoretical jump. Some guidance would be great.
Also, why exactly do we require $$p_{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})\delta x_1\delta x_2 = p_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{y})\delta y_1\delta y_2 ?$$
In my head it makes sense as we want to preserve the underlying probability, but it would be nice to have it in more technical terms.
Any help would be appreciated

I think what you're looking for is $p_y({\mathbf y}) = p_x({\mathbf x}) |det({\mathbf J})|$, where $det({\mathbf J})$ is the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation, i.e. $J_{ij} = \partial x_i / \partial y_j$. The expression you have for the two dimensional case is true for the special case of coordinate transformations consisting of independent stretches/translations in the two directions.

Do you have a link to a relatively good derivation of that relationship?

There's some good discussion in the wikipedia article on the Jacobian matrix and its determinant and the links therein. Basically, $|det({\mathbf J})|$ is the ratio of the initial volume to the final volume of an infinitesimal volume element under a coordinate transform. When applying this to probability density functions, a volume element contains the same "amount of probability" before the transformation vs. after. Therefore you need to multiply by the ratio of volumes to get the probability density correct.

Yes, there is a derivation of the Jacobian but not the relationship between probability densities: $p_y(y)=p_x(x)|det(J)|$

Your extended explanation is great. Makes sense

In my opinion, your difficulty is about the notation. Notations like $\frac{dx}{dy}$ are discouraged. Once you use a good notation, the change of variable formula will rigorously yield a similar formula in $\mathbb{R}^d$ using Jacobian. I shall give the formula in the way I usually apply it, which is slightly more general than your version.
Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued random variable defined on probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ with Lebesgue density $p_X$. For a given transform $T : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, put $Y = T(X)$. We show that $Y$ has a Lebesgue density $p_Y$ and we compute it.
The assumption we shall make on $T$ is that there exists a countable collection of Borel sets $A_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ such that every restriction $T \mid_{A_i}:A_i \to \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies the assumption of change of variable formula on $A_i$ and that $P \{X - \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\}=0$. To simplify, let us write $T_i$ in place of $T \mid_{A_i}$ and $T_i^{-1}$ for its inverse.
If, as in the most usual case, each $T_i$ is continuously differentiable with continuously differentiable inverse, then you have no problem applying what is below.
For a given Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, we have :
\begin{equation*}
P \{Y \in B\} = P\{T(X) \in B\} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P \{X \in T_i^{-1}(B), X \in A_i\} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{T_i^{-1}(B)} \chi_{A_i}(x) p_X(x)dx
\\ = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{B} \chi_{A_i}(T_i^{-1}(x)) p_X(T_i^{-1}(x))
\mid \det (DT_i^{-1}(x))\mid dx
\\ = \int_B \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \chi_{T(A_i)}(x) p_X(T_i^{-1}(x))
\mid \det (DT_i^{-1}(x))\mid dx
\end{equation*}
Here $\chi$ is my notation for indicator functions, with $\chi_A(x)=1$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ otherwise. $DT_i^{-1}(x)$ means the matrix of total derivative of $T_i^{-1}$ evaluated at $x$.
The last equality uses Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem.
Since $B$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $Y$ has a Lebesgue density $p_Y(y)$ given by :
\begin{equation*}
p_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \chi_{T(A_i)}(y) p_X(T_i^{-1}(y))
\mid \det (DT_i^{-1}(y))\mid
\end{equation*}
In the most often case, $T$ is invertible. To simplify the formula in this case, put $A_1 = \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A_i = \emptyset$ otherwise to get :
\begin{equation*}
p_Y(y) =  p_X(T^{-1}(y))
\mid \det (DT^{-1}(y))\mid
\end{equation*}
The above more general formula is necessary in practice even when $d = 1$ to compute densities like $\mid X \mid$ and $\sin X$.
